# Display connected with DisplayPort-DVI cable not detected

Tags: display

I've connected an old display via DisplayPort-DVI cable and it's not detected. The modern display connected with DisplayPort works fine. Relevant output from `lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
```

`xrandr` says that everything except primary display is disconnected.

The PC is HP EliteBook 840G3, Ubuntu is 16.04.

Comment: How did you determine it is not detected? I mean, did you for example check the output of `xrandr` ??

Comment: @WillemK it says everything except the built-in display is disconnected

Comment: Well.. That lets me thinking either that old display is broken or the DP-DVI cable is.